# Having trouble getting my mysql table to update

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This is the form I use to edit my table:

```
<?php

    // get value of id that sent from address bar
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    // Retrieve data from database...
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chart WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // Output the loop...
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <form action="./include/update.php" method="post">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $row['date']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="nuvolog_am" name="nuvolog_am" value="<?php echo $row['nuvolog_am']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="nuvolog_noon" name="nuvolog_noon" value="<?php echo $row['nuvolog_noon']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="nuvolog_pm" name="nuvolog_pm" value="<?php echo $row['nuvolog_pm']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="predisone" name="predisone" value="<?php echo $row['predisone']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="norvase" name="norvase" value="<?php echo $row['norvase']; ?>" /></td>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="17"><input type="text" id="symptoms" name="symptoms" value="<?php echo $row['symptoms']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="17"><input type="submit" value="Add Records"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </form>
        <? }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    } 

    // Close the connection...
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

And this is the update.php

```
<?php    

    // Database credentials...
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "...";
    $password = "...";
    $dbname = "...";

    // Database connection...
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check the connection...
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // update data in mysql database 
    $sql="UPDATE chart SET 
        id            = '$id',
        date            = '$date',
            nuvolog_am      = '$nuvolog_am',
            nuvolog_noon    = '$nuvolog_noon',
            nuvolog_pm      = '$nuvolog_pm',
            predisone       = '$predisone',
            norvase         = '$norvase'
    WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // When chart is submitted...
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    // Close the connection...
    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

It's probably something very simple, but I cannot figure out why this won't update the records database. I'm hoping somebody can help me figure this out.

Comment: 1)You are mixing mysql and mysqli 2) your script is open for sql injection 3)You are not define any variable `$id'..`and so on

Comment: You should not be throwing those variables directly into your sql statement, that is open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `$result=mysql_query($sql);` to mysqli code.

like

```
$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";
$conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the table using `$result=mysql_query($sql);` while to connect you used `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

By the way you should delete this question (if it's possible) or change all your passwords if the password that appears in the old version is used for other accounts too (you can see the edit history).

Answer (score 0):

to run query use this

```
$conn->query($sql);
```